# Helm upgrade fails with error: expects " or n, but found t

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to add a new pod to my helm chart, it passes validation (helm lint) but fails at last stage of deployment:

> Mon Dec 16 10:01:58 2019 INFO    Running helm install/upgrade for
>   xyz-stg
>   UPGRADE FAILED Error:  "" is invalid: patch: Invalid value:
>   "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\"
>   (...)
>   ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte
>   of ...|,"value":true},{"nam|..., bigger context ...|"value":"stg"},
>   (...)
>   Error: UPGRADE FAILED:  "" is invalid: patch: Invalid value:
>   "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":
>   (...)
>   ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte
>   of ...|,"value":true},{"nam|..., bigger context ...|"value":"stg"},
>   (...) Mon Dec 16 10:02:09 2019 ERROR   Upgrade/Installation of xyz-stg
>   failed

I have no idea what this error means or how to even debug it. It sounds like some syntax indentation error, but all I did was: copy-pasted the pod configuration from other working pod and changed all names.

Comment: you have an empty value somewhere in your chart.

Comment: @c4f4t0r Based on this error (it's longer) is there a way to find which variable is empty? When I change anything I get `configMap already exists in the cluster` error.
Anyhow, it does create the POD regardless, although it's pending due to some tainted nods - are these errors related in any way?

Comment: helm template can help you

Comment: The actual error here is:

```
expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|,"value":true}
```

So there is a piece in the Deployment yaml with

```yaml
"value":  true
```

But it wants:


```yaml
"value":  "true"
```

Answer (score 50):

I ran into a similar problem and apparently it turns out Kubernetes's Pod specification requires environment variable values to be coerced as strings, so integers need to be passed through quote.So, in your `deployment.yaml` file wherever you are using the numeric values try to pass them as below.

```
value: {{ .Values.environment.TEMP | quote}}
```

It will work just fine after that. Hope it helps

Comment: I found out that a value of "True" or "False" needs to be quoted as well

Answer (score 12):

Add double quotes and update the deployment.yaml with following changes

In `deployment.yaml` file

```
        value: {{ .Values.environment.TEMP }}
        value: {{ quote .Values.environment.TEMP }}
```

In `Values.yaml` file

```
Envrionment:
  TEMP: "true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Helm lint - Will not capture this error.
For env values / Boolean check - It is recommended to use quote. Below is an example, Assuming `zookeeperConnectionTimeout` has an entry in `values.yml`

```
value: {
    {
        .Values.zookeeperConnectionTimeout | quote
    }
}
```

To Check:
You can use helm template to see the actual substituted values before applying install.

Actual substituted value will be something like below:

```
value: "180000"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this adding an annotation from PowerShell.  Tried several things before discovering `<double><single><value><single><double>`

```
helm upgrade userprofile $helmfile.ToString() --install --wait --timeout 90s
--set ingress.annotations."nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth"="'1'"
--set ingress.annotations."nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream"="'false'"
```

In Azure DevOps HelmDeploy@0 task arguments I needed `<double><single><single><value><single><single><double>`.

```
  - task: HelmDeploy@0
    displayName: 'Install UserProfile'
    inputs:
      ...
      command: upgrade
      arguments: '
        ...
        --set ingress.annotations."nginx\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/auth-tls-verify-depth"="''1''"
        --set ingress.annotations."nginx\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream"="''false''"'
```