# Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes-helm, datadog

Per [this spec](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/kube_scheduler/datadog_checks/kube_scheduler/data/conf.yaml.example) on github and these [helm instructions](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set)  I'm trying to upgrade our Helm installation of datadog using the following syntax:

```
helm upgrade datadog-monitoring --set datadog.confd."kube_scheduler\.yaml".instances[0].prometheus_url="http://localhost:10251/metrics",datadog.confd."kube_scheduler\.yaml".init_config= stable/datadog
```

However I'm getting the error below regardless of any attempt at altering the syntax of the `prometheus_url` value (putting the url in quotes, escaping the quotes, etc):

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: v1.ConfigMap.Data: ReadString: expects " or n, but found {, error found in #10 byte of ...|er.yaml":{"instances|..., bigger context ...|{"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"kube_scheduler.yaml":{"instances":[{"prometheus_url":"\"http://localhost|...

If I add the `--dry-run --debug` flags I get the following yaml output:

```
REVISION: 7
RELEASED: Mon Mar  2 14:28:52 2020
CHART: datadog-1.39.7
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
datadog:
  confd:
    kube_scheduler.yaml:
      init_config: ""
      instances:
      - prometheus_url: http://localhost:10251/metrics
```

The Yaml output appears to mesh with the integration as specified on this [github page](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/kube_scheduler/datadog_checks/kube_scheduler/data/conf.yaml.example).

Comment: sometime you may face problem on APP_PORT: "8080". In this case you need to parse to integer in your code. But using double or single quote will resolve the issue

Comment: This has been answered here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354115/helm-upgrade-fails-with-error-expects-or-n-but-found-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354115/helm-upgrade-fails-with-error-expects-or-n-but-found-t)

Comment: This has been answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354115/helm-upgrade-fails-with-error-expects-or-n-but-found-t

Answer (score 25):

So, the problem, as I can understand, is due to the **ConfigMap** configuration. I've faced the same with the following config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
  labels:
    group: mock
data:
  APP_NAME: my-mock
  APP_PORT: 8080
  APP_PATH: /api
```

And I have solved it only by surrounding all the values with quotes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
  labels:
    group: mock
data:
  APP_NAME: "my-mock"
  APP_PORT: "8080"
  APP_PATH: "/api"
```

Comment: sometime you may face problem on APP_PORT: "8080". In this case you need to parse to integer in your code. But using double or single quote will resolve the issue.